# Thread Context vs. Thread ID - using CoreData with Async Await

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, core-data, asynchronous

We are using CoreData in a Xamarin iOS C# project.  Due to a concurrency issue the developers in charge of this area engineered code that tests that the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == 1` and if that fails an exception is thrown per the code below:

```
public static NSManagedObjectContext ManagedObjectContext {
get
{
    if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == 1)
    {
        return MainMOC;
    }
    else
    {
            if (_context == null) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            // Hey, don't ignore this exception, fix it
            // if you don't fix it, all values coming from core data are suspect
            throw new Exception("attempting to use a temp context without calling BeginBackgroundContext()");
        }
        return _context;
    }
}
```

}

This forces developers to use a code pattern for any background calls to be such as the following:

```
InvokeInBackground(()=> {

NSManagedObjectContext context = new NSManagedObjectContext(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueue);
context.ParentContext = DataSource.MainMOC;
context.PerformAndWait(() => {

    try {

        DataSource.SetContextForThread(context);

        // update the UI
        this.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate
            {

            // do your code here

            });
    } catch (Exception e) {

            // log exception here
    }

});
DataSource.ClearContextForThread();
```

}

Is this really necessary for threading such as creating a NSManagedObjectContext, perform code, then save the context?  It is my belief this is overkill and too restrictive.  Rather than testing the Thread ID should we only be concerned about the Thread CONTEXT? Now I'm not sure if thread context and ID are one in the same but I believe they are different.  The context I'm assuming is essentially UI Thread and Background thread.  So if we create a context on the UI thread, use async await on a method with .ConfigureAwait(true) to ensure we return on the called "context" the code should still work?  As it stands now if you use async await knowing you are not guaranteed to return on the same context much less the same thread ID the trap the engineers created in the top code block will cause a failure (intentional).

I want to only write code as complicated as needed so what is really required with CoreData knowing the single threaded nature of the SQLite backend and still have the ease of coding with async await and backgrounding in C#?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is not thread safe and you are required to create new ManagedObjectContext for each thread. ManagedObjectContext are cheap, so it’s not an overkill. For async/await using moc.Perform() should work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you provide sample code of using mod.Perform() with async await safely and not cause a threading issue when await Foo() returns? Thanks

Comment: @Neal Unfortunately not, because I still didn't write any .Net code for iOS yet :) (although I'm .Net developer, I use Objective-C). Anyway, I'll try to write example code, but I don't promise...